# What's the name of an object in the slice category?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, slice-category

What do you call an object of the [slice category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category)? I have been calling them "slices" but this seems to be wrong: it seems that people use the word "slice" as a synonym of "slice category", *not* as a name for their objects.

Edit: The most generally applicable term for an object of $\mathcal C / X$ seems to be "object over $X$". This has a few drawbacks:

- It requires mentioning $X$ all the time, which gets annoying when we are working in a slice category over a fixed $X$ for a longer time,
- "Over $X$" is an adverbial clause, which makes it sound like it's a property, when it's actually structure. An object over $X$ is not an object of $\mathcal C$. The phrase "a morphism of/between objects over $X$" (or even just "a morphism over $X$"?) does not really ring the bell that the forgetful functor $\Sigma_X : \mathcal C / X \to \mathcal C$ may not be full.

Comment: an arrow over $c$

Comment: $c$-valued characteric map viewed as an object? Or $c$-valued abstract property?

Answer (score 4):

As the nlab article already indicates: objects of $\mathcal{C}/X$ are called **objects over $X$**, or more precisely $\mathcal{C}$-objects over $X$. They are typically written as
$$\begin{array}{c} Y \\ \downarrow \\ X \end{array}$$
See also [Stacks/001G](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/001G). Similarly, objects of $X / \mathcal{C}$ are called objects under $X$.

Comment: The nlab article literally doesn't contain the strings "object over" and "objects over".
More importantly, this terminology is clumsy in that you have to repeat $X$ every time, even when it's clear from the context what $X$ you were thinking of. I would like a word like "over-object" or "pre-object". I guess I could go for "slice object".

Comment: I wrote "indicates". The reference to X is important, since different X give different things. For example, coverings of X.

Comment: Of course it is important that author and reader have the same $X$ in mind. But we have terminology to speak of vector spaces without mentioning the field every time, or to speak of group actions when the concerned group is fixed.

Comment: An example of a situation where we are working with slices over one fixed object for an extended time, is when working with a fixed [parametric right adjoint](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/parametric+right+adjoint) functor.

Comment: Still about the first comment: there is no need to reinvent the term, it is already established. See for example my Stacks Project Link.

Comment: About your other comment: it doesn't make much sense to have such a name here which doesn't have X or the category in it because the situation is so general. But Kevin Arlin's answer is a good addition here. When C consists of spaces, C/X consists of spaces over X, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When $\mathcal C$ is a category of spaces (in the broadest sense), then objects in the slice category $\mathcal C/X$ are often called $X$-bundles. This is especially so in algebraic geometry and in topology. The idea is that an object $p:Y\to X$ is a collection of fibers $Y(x)=p^{-1}(x)$ indexed by the base space $X$. You can draw $Y\to X$ as a bundle of lines (the fibers) each sitting over their corresponding $x\in X$. When you take this very seriously, then you end up with dependent type theory.

Edit: Here some more names which go into the same direction, but do not indicate that the space might be locally a projection map. You can call $X \to S$ also an $S$-indexed space, or an $S$-indexed family of spaces.

Comment: I do not fully agree. The word bundle includes a local triviality condition.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I agree that it often does, but i have also seem several books/texts where everything is called a bundle (especially type theorists like to do this). I will add an example when i happen to stumble over one

Comment: I've seen this but I think it's very uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

Many algebraic geometry papers take place in the slice category of schemes over some base scheme $S.$ In practice, "scheme over $S$" is used very often in these contexts, but "$S$-scheme" is a common abbreviation, as is $k$-scheme for a $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$-scheme when $k$ is a commutative ring, especially a field. In my experience, there is never any abbreviation that throws out the $S$ while emphasizing the slice, because that's not how these objects are thought of. This terminology could be exported to many contexts: if the objects of $\mathcal C$ are widgets, then an object of $\mathcal C/X$ could readily be called $X$-widgets, though the familiarity of the language will vary with context.